# How to resolve require() of ES modules is not supported

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, mocha.js, es6-modules

I'm trying to use the `split-on-first` library for a project, but I am unable to import it.

I have converted the entire project to TypeScript and changed this line to use `import` instead of `require`.

```
import splitOnFirst from 'split-on-first';
```

However, when I try to run my unit tests, I still receive this error:

```
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module: <project>\code\node_modules\split-on-first\index.js
require() of ES modules is not supported.
require() of <project>\code\node_modules\split-on-first\index.js from <project>\code\helpers\fileReview.ts is an ES module file as it is a .js file whose nearest parent package.json contains "type": "module" which defines all .js files in that package scope as ES modules.
Instead rename index.js to end in .cjs, change the requiring code to use import(), or remove "type": "module" from <project>\code\node_modules\split-on-first\package.json.
```

My `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "lib": [
      "es2019"
    ],
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "target": "ES2017",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "outDir": "./build",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "strict": true
  },
  "include": ["./**/*"],
  "exclude": ["**/*.spec.ts"]
}
```

I run the unit tests through `package.json`: `nyc mocha './tests/**/*.test.ts'`

What am I doing wrong? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you change `compilerOptions.module` to `esnext`?

Comment: Just tried it, but unfortunately to no avail. I've also removed `target` with it, but that also did nothing.

Comment: @Lex Bumping against a similar issue. Did you figure it out?

Comment: @tivoni sadly, no. I circumvented the issue by removing the library and writing my own function.